# Python invalid syntax on multi-var except statement in python3

Tags: python

When trying to import some package I get the following trace :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-6-9c5db07d999b>", line 1, in <module>
    import vmfusion

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vmfusion/__init__.py", line 254
    except AttributeError, e:
```

I tried to check it by minimal example and got the same results. but it worked in python2. Perhaps do you know how should i fix the code in python3 ?

Comment: The library seems to be Python 2 only. Look for an alternative!

Comment: Yeah that `except` line is Python 2 syntax. It would be unreasonable for you as a user to edit whole library to work with Python 3. If the developers didn't make a Python 3-compatible version and you HAVE to use this library, then use Python 2 in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for that kind of `except` clause changed from Python 2 to Python 3. In Python 3, you would use `except AttributeError as e`.

This error suggests to me that the module you're loading may not be compatible with Python 3 (this may only be the *first* error you'd encounter using it). You should check if it has a newer version that's been updated to be compatible, or if some fork of it exists with updated code. Even if you don't need any Python 3-speicfic features, code that only works in Python 2 probably hasn't had any bugs fixed in many years (which might be fine for very stable code bases, but is not as good as active maintenance).